# Custom UITextViewDelegate/UITextFieldDelegate not called

Tags: ios, swift, delegates, swift3

Attempting to create custom delegate classes for `UITextViewDelegate` and `UITextFieldDelegate`. When I set these classes to be their own delegate, or set another UIKit component as their delegate, everything works fine. However, if I create my own class to serve as the delegate, the delegate methods are never called. Why?

**This works:**

```
class MyTextView: UITextView, UITextViewDelegate {
  required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    self.delegate = self
}

func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
  print("I work")
}
```

**This does not:**

```
class MyTextView: UITextView {
  required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    self.delegate = MyDelegate()
}

class MyDelegate: NSObject, UITextViewDelegate {
  func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
    print("I work")
  }
}
```

**Note:** If `MyDelegate` does not subclass `NSObject`, the following error is thrown:

`/// Type 'MyDelegate' does not conform to protocol 'NSObjectProtocol'`

Comment: Hi you need to keep a reference to MyDelegate class, or it will get dealloc.

Comment: #Facepalm! I JUST ran into this issue with another class. Will give that a shot; thanks!

Comment: @koropok Looking back at it, shouldn't the `delegate` field itself maintain a reference to MyDelegate?

Comment: hmm, you're right, my bad.

Comment: In usual Cocoa/Cocoa Touch classes, `delegate` only keeps weak reference. To make the delegate work properly, it needs to be kept somewhere else with strong reference.

Comment: I just tested, keeping a strong reference will work, like what @OOPer said.

Comment: When I tested the first time I tested the wrong class :p. Someone post an answer I can accept :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when you set the text field delegate in the second case you are creating a weak reference of the MyDelegate() class. You can check the following code, this will resolve your problem by creating a strong reference of MyDelegate().

```
class MyTextView: UITextView {
    var responseDelegate = MyDelegate()
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        self.delegate = responseDelegate
    }
}
class MyDelegate: NSObject, UITextViewDelegate {
    func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
        print("I work")
    }
}
```